# Failed to upload file to Coverity for analysis

Tags: python-3.x, coverity

I am trying to follow instruction and integrate Coverity into my CI pipeline. However, I failed to upload the files to Coverity with curl, as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvHRm.png)

When I run the following command:
curl --form token= \ --form email= \ --form project= \ --form file=@App_cov_scan.tgz \ --form version="Version" \ --form description="Description" \ https://scan.coverity.com/builds

it shows:
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
Error: Process completed with exit code 3.

Could anyone please advise how to solve this issue?

Thanks